# How To Save An Array Via Form Data And Ajax PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, multipartform-data

How to save an all value of multi-select when it was along with file via formdata. It always show file "Invalid arguments for foreach()". Even thought the file has been save into respective folder but the multi-select options didn't come into foreach and save into database.

**Warning: Invalid arguments supplied in foreach()**

The following codes I am using.

HTML

```
<!--JQUERY-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <!--Bootstrap 3.3.7-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <!--Font-awesome 4.7.0-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<button class="btn btn-success addnewjob" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_new_record_modal">Add New Job</button>


<!-- Modal - Add New Record/User -->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="add_new_record_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add New Record</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <select name="test[]" id="sbTwo" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
              <option value="PAPER CUP">PAPER CUP</option>
              <option value="PAPER BOWL">PAPER BOWL</option>
              <option value="PAPER PLATE">PAPER PLATE</option>
              <option value="PAPER BAG">PAPER BAG</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <label for="jspec_filedoc">DOC Files</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <label class="input-group-btn">
                <span class="btn btn-info">
                                                        <span class="fa fa-file-image-o"></span>
                <input id="jspec_filedoc" name="jspec_filedoc" type="file" accept=".doc, .docx,.xlsx" style="display: none;" multiple>
                </span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="existingaifile" placeholder="Document File" readonly>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addRecord()">Add Record</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- // Modal -->
```

SCRIPT

```
function addRecord() {

  var conf = confirm("Are you sure, do you really want to APPROVE this file?");
  if (conf == true) {
    // get values

    $('#sbTwo option').prop('selected', true); //select all data in multiselect
    var test = $("#sbTwo").val();
    var pj_schednum = $('#pj_schednum').val();
    var jspec_filedoc = $('#jspec_filedoc').prop('files')[0];

    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('jspec_filedoc', jspec_filedoc);
    form_data.append('pj_schednum', pj_schednum);
    alert(form_data.append('test', test));

    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax/createjob.php',
      dataType: 'text',
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: form_data,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    });
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {

    $(document).on('change', ':file', function() {
      var input = $(this),
        numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
        label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
      input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(':file').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {
        var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
          log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;

        if (input.length) {
          input.val(log);
        } else {
          if (log) alert(log);
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['pj_schednum']) && isset($_POST['test']) && isset($_FILES['jspec_filedoc']))
    {
        // include Database connection file 
        include("db_connection.php");

        //get current date with 24 hours time format
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
        $a = date('m/d/Y H:i:s'); 
        $b = date('m/d/Y h:i A', strtotime($a));
        $z = date('mdYHis');    

        // get values 
        $file_name3 = explode(".", $_FILES['jspec_filedoc']['name']); 
        $new_name3 = rand() . '.'. $file_name3[1];  
        $sourcePath3 = $_FILES["jspec_filedoc"]["tmp_name"];
        $savethisname3='JT'.$z.$new_name3;        
        $targetPath3 = "../bin/jobs_attachments/docfile/".$savethisname3;  
        move_uploaded_file($sourcePath3, $targetPath3);  


        $i = 0;
        foreach ($_POST['test'] as $operation_processname){  
            echo $operation_processname."\n";

            $operation_step=$i++;//The steps

            $query = "INSERT INTO operation (o_name, o_step, o_doc, o_added) VALUES('$operation_processname', '$operation_step','$savethisname','$b')";
            if (!$result = mysqli_query($db, $query)) {
                exit(mysqli_error());
            }
        }

        echo "1 Record Added!";
    }
?>
```

RESULT

```
+-----------------------------------+
+o_name| o_step| o_doc| o_added     |
+-----------------------------------+
|PAPER CUP |0 |doc1.docx | 01/11/2017 05:16:45 PM|
|PAPER BOWL|0 |doc2.docx | 01/12/2017 05:16:45 PM|
|PAPER PLATE|0 |doc3.docx | 01/13/2017 05:16:45 PM|
|PAPER BAG|0 |doc4.docx | 01/14/2017 05:16:45 PM|
+------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: can you show your $_POST dump data here ?

Comment: your jQuery version?

Comment: @MuhammadAkberKhan I'm getting all options value of multiselect but it didn't pass though the foreach. I got exact data when I echo the `$_POST['test'];` I am using `jquery-1.12.3.min.js`.

Comment: just want to check $_POST index, there may be some space in key? like $_POST['test '], share this test index we can sort it out

Comment: if you have tried to use the "echo" function and it display all you data it seams like it's a string, not an array, you have to explode it too

Comment: @MacBooc Yeah I just try to check if theirs some data transfered that's why I use echo. But when I try to use it in `foreach()` it goes to invalid. I always got **Warning: Invalid arguments supplied for foreach().**

Comment: share your $_POST data completely aor specifically test index, then we can suggest solution

Comment: @MuhammadAkberKhan  My test index is the html part of the this post and all of it I am using.

Comment: ok, just want to check in $_POST, is it posting correctly as an array or not

Comment: @Ailyn show us how echo print the $_POST['test']

Comment: @MacBooc I just edit the question and I added the expected output of this problem.

Comment: You still don't show us what would be the problem, either you show us what is the output of form_data in a console.log just before the ajax or you do a var_dump($_POST) in the top of your php file and post the output (you have to use the inspector of your browser in the part "network" click on the last line which should be you ajax request and post the output of the section "response")

Comment: @MacBooc https://github.com/Ailyn09/project102/blob/master/Capture11.PNG

Comment: @Ailyn you have to set your form and click on the button which trigger the ajax request before :)

Comment: @MacBooc What do you mean by that? How can I do that? What is the possible output of that?

Comment: Wait if you click on the button which trigger the ajax, the page is reload or not ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152513/discussion-between-ailyn-and-macbooc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send your data by getting like`var test = $("#sbTwo").val();` .So when you access from php ,it will access as a string eg `item1,item2` .So try `explode` first before you loop .

```
$test = explode(",",$_POST['test']);
```

Comment: Thanks works fine. It totally explode the array data and convert into array. Then save, the same with my expected results.